# opening data file or image in specific folder in package

Tags: ros, package, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to access a specific folder to open a data file or image in an ROS package? I suppose I could find the environmental variable HOME then write the full path by adding the strings, but it seems like there would be a more simple way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202849/opening-data-file-or-image-in-specific-folder-in-package/) by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The more portable way to do this is to use [getPath](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roslib/html/c++/namespaceros_1_1package.html#ae9470dd201aa4e66abb833e710d812a4). This gets the addresyo of the specified package, then you can drill down to the specific directory. Note that this requires that the package is findable on the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) with karma: 253 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-11**:
Note that apparently the `roslib` Python library is [deprecated](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roslib/html/python/roslib.packages-module.html) (from [roslib.packages is deprecated, what's its successor?](http://answers.ros.org/question/202822/roslibpackages-is-deprecated-whats-its-successor/)).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-02-11**:
[rospkg](http://wiki.ros.org/rospkg) was the 2nd generation, and [catkin_pkg](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_pkg) is the catkin aware library